# Как перевести полученный через API текст на другой язык

Tags: html, api, перевод

Я получаю запросом через API состояние Трек номера (Посылки) на английском языке, например: "Post Office Collection"
У меня сайт на русском языке, как мне переводить эти строки на русский язык?

Answer (score 0):

Используй API переводчика Yandex или Google. Они платные, но у Google есть бесплатное количество знаков доступных бесплатно каждый месяц. Так же можешь кэшировать ответы от API